# Geoserver GetFeatureInfo WMS attributes: how to hide geometry?

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I know this has been discused before, but before somebody tell me about data base views or HTML templates, this is my concern:

Geoserver returns the geometry field from WMS getfeature info, enabling anyone to create scripts to download the data from the server as if it was WFS.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTTP parameter "propertyName" to specify the properties that you want to be returned (comma-separated list), e.g. `&propertyName=name,category`. So, if you want all attributes, except for the geometry to be returned, you must include all property names in this list.

See: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo for all details.

Comment: The issue though is that the provider of the GeoServer service wants to stop the Geometry from being provided.  propertyName is a way of a user making a request for data, not a way for a provider to stop data from being published.

Comment: In that case you need to fall back to HTML output only (see other response to this question) and edit the FeatureInfo template to not display the Geometry.

Comment: Is it possible like &propertyName!=Name

Comment: @Hyma That is unfortunately not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

With the admin utility you can select allowed formats from the WMS settings page. GetFeatureFormats can be selected from "Allowed MIME types for a GetFeatureInfo request".  Leave only text/html and text/plain left. You must also disable vector formats from "Allowed MIME types for a GetMap request" for preventing KML and perhaps SVG and some other outputformats.

Comment: I think this might solve it, but I was thinking of something like the "gml_include_items" of MapServer, without sacrificing GML output.